# Why this Variable does not pass correctly in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have a simple JQuery Statement...and my question is, why in the world does one of these fail?

Lets assume the variable `colorAttribute` is `color`

```
    $(thisCLass).css( "color", '#'+hex ); // Works when written
    $(thisCLass).css( colorAttribute, '#'+hex ); // Works with variable

    $(thisCLass).css({ "color" : '#'+hex }); // Works when written  
    $(thisCLass).css({ colorAttribute : '#'+hex }); // Does not Work with variable
```

Any ideas as to why the one fails?

Comment: Thank you to everyone who answered so quickly! I wish I could accept all of your answers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you can't use a variable to specify a name in an object literal.

An identifier in an object literal can be written with or without quotes, so it won't be interpreted as a variable in either case. The object will end up with the identifier that you specify:

```
{ "colorAttribute" : '#'+hex }
```

You can use a variable to set a property in an object, but then you have to create the object first and use the bracket syntax:

```
var obj = {};
obj[colorAttribute] = '#'+hex;
$(thisCLass).css(obj);
```

Comment: Ok, this answer makes the most sense to me... The understanding that the identifier can be written with or without quotes explains the issue. I assume that the value can be a variable though, since it works with the value as a variable.

Comment: @VIDesignz: Yes, the value can be any expression.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because you simply cannot do that in JavaScript. In an object literal, the left side of a property declaration is either a string literal or an identifier. If it's an identifier, then the identifier itself is used *as if* it were a string literal.

You can create an object however and populate a property from a variable:

```
var cssProps = {};
cssProps[colorAttribute] = '#' + hex;
$(thisClass).css(cssProps);
```

Answer (score 4):

because the second one becomes an object with just one property: "colorAttribute".

you should do this:

```
myobj = {};
myobj[collorAttribute] = "#"+hex;
$(thisClass).css(myobj);
```

perhaps you're a python programmer, but javascript is not like that regarding dicts (objects here). it happens often.

Answer (score 4):

Object literals/initializers take identifier keys just for their name, not for any values they may represent as a variable. So...

```
{ colorAttribute: '#' + hex }
```

...defines an `Object` with a key named `"colorAttribute"`.

You'll have to use bracket notation to name a key based on a variable:

```
var css = {};
css[colorAttribute] = '#' + hex;
$(thisClass).css(css);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't declare a javascript object literal with a variable for the property name.  A property name in a literal must be the actual property name, not a variable.

Instead, if you want to use a variable in the object form, you'd have to construct the object first and then pass it in:

```
var obj = {};
obj[colorAttribute] = '#'+hex;
$(thisCLass).css(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are doing `{ colorAttribute : '#'+hex }` you are creating a new object with a property named "colorAttribute".

I don't know exactly what you need but you could try

```
var cssObject = {};
cssObject[colorAttribute] = '#'+hex;
//cssObject[otherAttribute] = 'otherValue';
$(thisCLass).css(cssObject);
```

Hope this was helpfull.

Answer (score 2):

You need a step before writing what you are trying to do here:

First create a variable:

```
var color = new Object();
color.colorAttribute = '#'+hex

$(thisCLass).css(color);
```